# Image built with Yocto has no login prompt after adding /data partition to wks file

Tags: yocto, partition

I am in the process of adding SWUpdate to my Yocto image.
I need a data partition for persistent data, i.e. config files.

However, when I add this partition to the wks file, the image no longer provides a login prompt after booting.

The wks file has five partitions, boot, preloader, root0, root1, and the problematic data partition.

```auto
part --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 1024 --size 16
part --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot-with-spl.sfp" --ondisk mmcblk --system-id=a2 --align 1024 --fixed-size 1M
part --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label root0 --align 1024
part --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label root1 --align 1024
part /data --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label data --align 1024 --size 16M
```

Commenting out the line for the data partition does bring back the login prompt.

The boot log is the same between an image with or without the data partition, except for the line:

```
 mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
```

being

```
 mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4 < p5 p6 >
```

on the image with the data partition, and the missing login prompt.

Am I missing something? How can adding a partition affect the booting process in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change:

```
part /data --ondisk mmcblk --fstype=ext4 --label data --align 1024 --size 16M
```

to

```
part /data --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label data --align 1024 --size 16M
```

Without that change, the `fstab` file is created wrong.
I do not know why this is the case but, [someone else had the same problem](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2016-February/028427.html)